# $X$ is the set of sequences in $[-1,1]$ with metric $(a_n,b_n)\mapsto\sup\{|a_n-b_n|:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $X$ is not separable.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove the following:

> $X$ is the set of sequences in $[-1,1]$ with metric $(a_n,b_n)\mapsto\sup\{|a_n-b_n|:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $X$ is not separable.

I have been thinking that if we take that $X$ is separable, then there must exist a countable dense subset of $X$ and I'm trying to show that no such subset exists on the given space with the aforementioned metric. But I'm having to deal with sets whose points are sequences, and I am getting stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to prove 1) any countable subset of $X$ can't be dense  or 2) a dense subset of $X$ can't be countable.

Comment: Hint: Let $D\subset X$ dense.Then consider $A$ , the set of all binary sequences.Then $d(x, y) =1$ for $x\neq y \in A$ . Since $A$ is uncountable and any two distinct ball $B(x, 1) $ and $B(y, 1) $ contains at least two distinct members of $D$ , $D$ is uncountable.

Answer (score -2):

A standard way to show that a metric space is not separable is trying to find an uncountable discrete set $Y\subset X$. Now, consider for all subsets  $A \subset \Bbb N$ the sequences
$$a_n^A = \cases{ 1 & if  $n \in A$ \\ 0 & if  $n \notin A$ }$$
The set
$$Y = \{ a^A : A \subset \Bbb N\}$$
has the discrete metric and it is uncountable.